# L'Ópéra, season 1, episode 1 - piano and chords music piece (at 27:54)

Tags: identify-this-song, piano

I would like to know what is the song that plays at instant 27:54 of the episode 1 of season 1 of [L'Ópéra TV series](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt13079194/).

You can watch it [here](https://www.rtp.pt/play/p12825/e743230/lopera-companhia-de-bailado) (note that the streaming is from a public portuguese TV channel, RTP, thus, there is no infrigement of rights by sharing such link).

After multiple attempts using Shazam, I was not able to identify this song.